# Move agents using another agent in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

How can I do that in a simple way?

I have a number of packages inside a node. I want to move those packages to another node using the agent Forklift.

Comment: Show what code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If your package agent was named 'package', you can use package.moveTo() or package.moveToInTime(). Each of these functions can be customised with various parameters, include a node.  Have a look here for more information https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/gis/Movement_GIS.html